# Ant java task: Exclude certain classes from classpath jar

Tags: java, ant, slf4j

In one ant script I call the execution of an java class like this:

```
<java  classname="some.java.class" fork="true">
    <classpath >
        <fileset dir="path/to/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

My problem is that through the latest addition of a jar, I now have two jars which bring the `slf4j` `StaticLoggerBinder` which results in a lot of warnings when executing the script.

Is there any way to exclude certain classes from the fileset/classpath?

Comment: Why not excluding the unnecessary jar?

Comment: That's possible in my case and the current solution I have implemented. But I don't really like this solution as it may not always be available when you need both (or more) jars which bring the StaticLogBinder (or another class you can't have more than once) so I would love to know if there is a way to do what I asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `exclude`?

```
<fileset dir="path/to/lib">
  <include name="*.jar" />
  <exclude name="exclude-me.jar" />
</fileset>
```

I haven't tried but I think it is possible to exclude certain classes.

- excludes: comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be excluded.
- excludesfile: name of a file; each line of this file is taken to be an exclude pattern.

Comment: That's possible in my case and the current solution I have implemented. But I don't really like this solution as it may not always be available when you need both (or more) jars which bring the StaticLogBinder (or another class you can't have more than once) so I would love to know if there is a way to do what I asked in the question (which is excluding certain Classes only).